# On Notification Click put my app to background

Tags: android, notifications, background-foreground

I am working on an functionality where I get notification for POI (Point of Interest )while the user is navigating through Google Navigation app (used background service to get location update ).

**scenario**

1) User clicks navigate button from my app

2) He is taken to Google Navigation with data to navigate

3) Now user receives `Notification` for POI , then he clicks on it and he is taken to my app (my app brought to foreground , still Google Navigation i in background)

4) Now user is seeing my app , now he clicks the same notification , In this case I must put my app to background , so that use now sees Google Navigation

**what i tried**

Bringing my app to foreground is achieved , but putting my app to background on Notification click is not achieved .

**moveTaskToBack(true)** this is what I came across, but how can I implement this in Notification click

**code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), B_Activity.class.getName()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("toFront", toFront);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: **moveTaskToBack(boolean bool)** is a method Of Actvity class . So you can only call it with activity reference. I don't thing that there is way to do it with intent . What you can do Call a activity in notification intent, and then validate the intent in activity if its in foreground.

Comment: moveTaskToBack(true) give experience of pressing home button . i.e every apps is put in background . I want only my app in bg so that user see  navigation app

Comment: i don't think moveTaskToBack(true) give experience of pressing home button for all apps . I just tested it . It works only for the calling app .

Comment: Yeah ... I also noticed... When I open my app from notification , If that activity is not opened (user pressed back button from B to A) , my app crashes.

Comment: What the crash about ?

Comment: The activity that my PendingIntent is looking for has no data to populate UI . i.e PendingIntent  recreates B. please see my PendingIntent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**moveTaskToBack(boolean bool)** is a method Of Activity class . So you can only call it with activity reference. I don't thing that there is way to do it with intent . What you can do send a broadcast in notification intent, and then validate the intent in activity if its in foreground -> call movetaskBack().

If your B_Activity has no Ui . Then just set null component in Pending Intent.
Use Local Broadcast to notify your currently running activity to call moveTaskToBack().

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.settaskback");//Your custom action goes here
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then send broadcast on notification click. The activity which will receive this broadcast will put task to background (only if its in forground)

```
final Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.settaskback");
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
        notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

You need to register a Local broadcast receiver for this action in Activity.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if(somecondition){
              moveTaskToBack(true);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Your idea of creating PendingIntent broadcast heped me .. Thanks. Answer accepted :)